# ItemsStackPanel keeps using cached items instead of recreating them each time

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` in my Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT app which also groups items. Group templates are defined, and they include `Rectangle` objects with `ImageBrush` objects for their `Fill` property.
The `ListView` has an `ItemsStackPanel` as its `ItemsPanel` to display the items and the groups.

The problem is, I think, the `ItemsStackPanel` reusing the item containers while virtualizing because the images get loaded and drawn once, but when I scroll, image orders get scrambled with some of them losing the images altogether, and image loading events of the `ImageBrush` don't get fired either, indicating items are cached.

I've tried setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` instead of `"Recycling"` on the `ItemsStackPanel` but doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you messing with the listview item objects in codebehind? I know this won't ever happen in WPF if you're doing it correctly with templates, but I think you're really in UWP and you just added the WPF tag in the hope of getting downvoted by irritable old men (didn't work in my case, maybe I'm not old or irritable enough).

Comment: The only thing I do is subscribe to ImageBrush.ImageFailed event to load a default image in case the main image can't be opened for some reason (but those handlers don't get hit after items are first created, only the first time). ItemsWrapGrid bound to the same source doesn't have this problem. Any ideas?

And I specifically said Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT is the platform, but I figured WPF is close enough that someone might have had the same issue and can help.

Comment: No ideas, sorry. If I were you though, I'd create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Usually for me, I find that I *can't* reproduce the issue in a simpler context, so I just compare the non-broken example with the broken real code and find the solution. But if you can write a MVCE that works (er, doesn't work, I mean), it'd be a huge help for anybody trying to help.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out handling `ImageBrush.ImageFailed` (or any other event) in the group header template of an `ItemsStackPanel` causes very weird behavior.

I didn't really solve the problem, just removed the event handlers and implemented another mechanism to load the default images when the main image file is not found.

I have another default image loaded in an `Image` and have the other `Image` placed on top of the first one, loading the actual image file. If loading fails, the one underneath shows.